# Threat protection on WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2

I am evaluating the WSO2 API Manager. From a security perspective I have a couple of question on the API Manager capabilities, which I was not able to find through the documentation:

1. Does WSO2 API Server support security features by detecting/checking the content on incoming messages for attacks, redirection/traffic routing? If yes, how does it support?
2. Do the GUI portals offered by WSO2 (API Portal, API Publisher, etc) enable protection against cross-site scripting, SQL injection and XML content or structural threats and viruses?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Ritwik

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, WSO2 API Manager's API Gateway is essentially an ESB and can check the content of incoming requests and detect message attacks. It is also possible to route traffic. You can direct access the API definition from the admin console of the API Manager (or directly from the file system)
2. Yes both the API Store and Publisher is secured against cross site scripting, SQL injection and XML content threats

Comment: Hi Nadeesha, Thanks for the answers. I do have a followup question on #1. 1. I understand that being an ESB it allows us to check/transform the content. Are the threat detection capabilities offered out-of-the box by WSO2, or does one have to write custom code to detect such attacks?

Comment: Threat protection can be achieved via synapse configuration no custom coding is required.